# Remove xmlns="" from element on output

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have a transformation that is adding two elements to be uploaded to a system. However the two element nodes are showing `xmlns=""` inside of them and I would like to remove them on the output file.

Our Transformation file is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Refs">  
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:element name="ChqNb">
                <xsl:value-of select="../RltdPties/Cdtr|UltmtCdtr"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <ClrSysRef><xsl:value-of select="../RltdPties/Dbtr|UltmtDbtr"/></ClrSysRef>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the output portion that is the issue is looking like:

```
<Refs>
    <EndToEndId>1234556789</EndToEndId>
    <ChqNb xmlns="">
       ZZZZZ
    </ChqNb>
    <ClrSysRef xmlns="">
       BS/BADAA
    </ClrSysRef>
</Refs>
```

And what I want the outcome to be is

```
<Refs>
    <EndToEndId>1234556789</EndToEndId>
    <ChqNb>
       ZZZZZ
    </ChqNb>
    <ClrSysRef>
       BS/BADAA
    </ClrSysRef>
</Refs>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you showed your input XML, but from your use of `xpath-default-namespace` in your XSLT, it suggests there is a `xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02"` declaration in your XML, so all elements you are copying in your XSLT will be in that namespace.

However, where you create new `ChqNb` and `ClrSysRef` in your XSLT, these will be in no namespace, as `xpath-default-namespace` only applies to unprefixed elements in xpath expressions (like the template match). To get it to work, you should also add a default namespace declaration to your XSLT too. This could go on `xsl:template` in this case

```
<xsl:template match="Refs" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02">  
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:element name="ChqNb">
            <xsl:value-of select="../RltdPties/Cdtr|UltmtCdtr"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <ClrSysRef><xsl:value-of select="../RltdPties/Dbtr|UltmtDbtr"/></ClrSysRef>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```